# "Trying to get property of non-object" in AJAX request using Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, laravel

I am building a page that loads content in it.

The page is called /ajax and in here I have a set of data that is pulled in and I basically use this as a url to grab data for loading more images into a container from the instagram php library I have used.

When I press 'load more' it thinks and in the 'network' tab in the console I see this:

> Trying to get property of non-object

The confusion here for me is when I access the url /ajax I get this in the page with the correct data in it:

`"data_text":"Philips #outfitgrid #barbour"` in the array of items so it is clearly there and it can be accessed but for some reason when the url is then passed with `/ajax?tag=folkclothing&max_tag_id=1377007699427&_=1377709072077` it blows up?

Here is my php for the ajax array:

```
  $images = array();
  $data_link = array();
  $data_id = array();
  $data_likes = array();
  $data_text = array();
  foreach ($media as $data) {
    $images[] = array(

        "data_url"=>$data->images->standard_resolution->url,
        "data_link"=>$data->link,
        "data_text"=>$data->caption->text,
        //"data_text" => array['$data->caption->text'],
        "data_id"=>$data->getId(),
        "data_likes"=>$data->likes->count,
        "data_like"=>$current_user->likes($data),
        "data_token"=>$token

    );
  }
  $object = (object)$data_text;
  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->getNextMaxTagId(),
    'images'  => $images,
    'data_text' => $data_text
  ));
```

And then I have ajax to get this data into the page:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/ajax',
          data: {
            tag: tag,
            max_tag_id: maxid
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          complete: function(){
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // Output data
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
            var $content = $('<article class="instagram-image"><form id="'+ data.images[i].data_token +'" class="forms status-'+ data.images[i].data_like +'" action="'+base+'" method="post"><a class="fancybox" rel="folk-1" href="' + data.images[i].data_url + '"><img alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" src="' + data.images[i].data_url + '" alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" /></a><div class="formSubmit-feedback"></div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+ data.images[i].data_id +'"><p>'+ data.images[i].data_likes +'</p></form></article>');
                var duration = 1000, n = 0.1;
              $content.appendTo('section#images');
              $item = $content.find('form');
              if( $item.hasClass("status-false") ){
                    $item.addClass("notLiked");
                    //$('.notLiked').find('button.unlike').hide();
                    $item.find('a').after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-like like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button>');
                }
                if( $item.hasClass("status-true") ){
                    $item.addClass("Liked");
                    //$('.Liked').find('button.like').hide();
                    $item.find('a').after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-unlike unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>');
                }
              });
            // Store new maxid
            $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
          }
```

Can anyone shed some light into why this may throw the error in my question. I have tried so many solutions but I am struggling to see what the solution is to it.

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: its on this line `"data_text"=>$data->caption->text`, this is taken from caption which is an array when targeted and it spits out a load of other items like `created_at, date_created` etc

Comment: Have you tried `"data_text" => $data->caption['text']`?

Comment: yes but that then threw the error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` and I tried this the first time so not sure why its being a pain!

Comment: `dd($data->caption)` make sure it matches your expectation.

Comment: Hi Hailwood How would that go into my current array? I have used "data_text" => dd($data->caption)

Comment: Use it before you start setting your variables.  It's just going to output all the properties of your object like `var_dump()` would so you can see what it actually contains and make sure what you are trying to output actually exists.  After it outputs, it will then `exit;` as well so the code won't continue.

Comment: yeah I see that and it does have content in it as it shows that string that I am trying to get through `dd($data->caption->text)` the issue is when I click load more it does not find the text and when I inspect Network and click the url and look at the preview I get this error in the page `Trying to get property of non-object`